# Excel file is not display in google picker using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker

I am using a google picker API for attachment. [This is the google API library.](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)

I am using a below code for the document display in picker.

```
var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                .setIncludeFolders(false)
                .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,text/plain,application/pdf,\n\
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet,\n\
        text/csv,image/svg+xml,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation')
                .setSelectFolderEnabled(false);
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                .setAppId(appId)
                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                .addView(docsView)
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                //.setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
```

This code is not displaying the document which was `created from the drive` , it is only display the documents which was `uploaded to drive`.

Is there any way to also display those document which was `created from the drive`?. I check the document but I cannot find anything that is helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replace the view with below view condition:

```
    // NEW VIEW
    var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
            docsView.setIncludeFolders(true);
            docsView.setSelectFolderEnabled(true);

   // OLD VIEW
    var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                    .setIncludeFolders(false)
                    .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,text/plain,application/pdf,\n\
            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet,\n\
            text/csv,image/svg+xml,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation')
                    .setSelectFolderEnabled(false);

 // THIS CODE WILL BE SAME
            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                    .setAppId(appId)
                    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                    .addView(docsView)
                    .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                    //.setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                    .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                    .build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
```